# How to call properties from other classes

Tags: viewcontroller, delegation

I have a ViewController Class hooked to a button with a method as follows:

```
 #import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.clickCount = 0;

    NSLog(@"Click count = %@", self.clickCount);

Some more code that sets an image for the button etc...

}
```

The property clickCount has been declared in the h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property int clickCount;
- (IBAction)BasicAction:(id)sender;

@end
```

What I would like to do, is create a different class that picks up this property clickCount and does something independently. I am a beginner so I have no idea how to do this. Should I create another generic class and create an instance of my view controller then access the property that way, and if so how would I get something basic to print to the console like i.e.:

```
if (instanceOfViewController.clickCount % 2 = 0){
    NSLog(@"Player 1 is playing");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Player 2 is playing");
}
```

I tried this but although the first NSLog with the click count appears, the other messages don't.

Or should I use delegation? If so, what is the best way to go about it?

I know I could just write everything in my view controller but, although I am just beginning to program -so my knowledge is very limited- I am trying to organise my program in a way that my view controller doesn't become really long. Also I am trying to think in term of different objects interacting with each other. Can you point me in the right direction?
Thanks